Android. How to save a file in a public directory of external storage correctly?
I want to save file in a public external storage. For this I use the following code:
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

However, starting with Android 10, this method is deprecated and it is recommended to use the Media Store API.
Here is my code:
override suspend fun saveFile(
        byteArray: ByteArray,
        fileName: String,
    ): Uri? {
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, fileName.getMimeType())
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

        val uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

         if (uri != null) {
            contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { outputStream ->
                outputStream.write(byteArray)
            }
        } 
        
        return uri
    }

However, in this case, android studio highlights an error for me:

Field requires API level 29 (current min is 21):
android.provider.MediaStore.Downloads#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

But as far as I understood from the documentation, the media store is also available on versions 29 and below. However, from this error I understand that for version 29 and below I need to use the old approach:
return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        saveFileToMediaStore(context, byteArray, fileName)
    } else {
        saveFileToExternalStorage(context, byteArray, fileName) // Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    }

Is this true? How to save a file in a public directory of external storage correctly, so that it works starting from API version 21 and higher?
Please, help me.

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is not deprecated anymore. Make sure that your compileSdkVersion is up to date.

@CommonsWare, So you can no longer use the media store?

Using the MediaStore is fine, though not necessarily to EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI on older versions of Android.
